# Inflating my own view type from a layout file?

Tags: android

I defined a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <ListView />
</LinearLayout>
```

and I want to use a wrapper class for it:

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {
    ListView mListView;

    public build() {
        mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
    }
}
```

not sure how to inflate this from my layout file:

```
MyView v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.myview, null);
```

the inflater of course does not know what 'MyView' type is, and returns only View. What's a good way to reconcile this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you inflate LinearLayout in linear layout ?
What you probably need, define a layout for myView. Inflate it in some sort of initialize procedure ( for that view ).
And than you'll use your new view in xml layout.
More on that here 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the type of the Layout in xml.

Instead of your xml you need to declare it like that:

```
<your.package.MyView>
 <ListView />
</MyView>
```